# How to subscribe while creating an observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have an observable emitting an ID. I want to retrieve an element with that Id and store it into a new observable. However, this observable needs to be subscribed to in order to emit its value. Currently the codeblock looks like this

```
selectedElement$ =
  latestElementId$.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    mergeMap(id => store$.select(selectElement(id))),
    tap(element => elementForm?.patchValue(element))
  );
selectedElement$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe();
```

I have the gut feeling that I am doing something wrong and that there is an operator that makes the last three lines obsolete. Without them however, the code is currently not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what it is you're trying to achieve by using tap to output an observable over and over, but this is how I would've written this code block:

```
// Set up our observables
latestElementId$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(23);
selectedElement$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

// Subscribe to latestElementId$
latestElementId$
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(
    // Avoid running multiple times for same value
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    // Whatever you're doing here
    mergeMap(id => store$.select(selectElement(id)))
  )
  .subscribe((element: any) => {
    // Patch the value to the form
    elementForm?.patchValue(element);

    // Update the selectedElement observable, notifying any subscribers
    selectedElement$.next(element);
  });
```